# How to zip/unzip data bytea on Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, oracle, zip, compression, gzip

As we have known, Oracle provided 2 functions UTL_COMPRESS.LZ_COMPRESS/LZ_UNCOMPRESS to compress the raw input. But when moving to aws Postgresql, there are no similar functions like that.
My question is how can we do compress and uncompress the raw data on Postgresql? Willing to listen to any solutions from you guys. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using RDS or EC2?

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL does that automatically for you through a feature called [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html). Values in a table row exceeding a size of 2000 bytes will get compressed and, if the row still exceeds 2000 bytes after that, sliced up and stored out of line. All that happens transparently.